# Anchor Link Breaking

Tags: html

**Problem:** I am trying to anchor particular sections of the webpage.

The following section are in the footer and will go to a particular section of a page based on the language.

The following below tags implemented on the page:

```
<p><a href="#Espanol"><strong>Spanish</strong></a><br />
    ATENCI&Oacute;N: si habla espa&ntilde;ol, tiene a su disposici&oacute;n servicios gratuitos de asistencia ling&uuml;&iacute;stica. Llame al 1-321-268-6111. (TTY: 1-800-955-8771)</p>
```

and the following is the footer:

```
<ul class="languages" style="margin-text-center:-30pt">
                <li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="/index.cfm/non-discrimination-and-language-assistance/#Espanol">Español (Spanish)</a></li></ul>
```

and I have also tried the following as well:

```
    <ul class="languages" style="margin-text-center:-30pt">
                <li class="langLI" style="list-style-type:none"><a href="#Espanol">Español (Spanish)</a></li></ul>
```

When I run my page, I get the following error: "**500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed**".

I am not sure which resource I page not to crash.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Set `id` not `href`. Also, remove the / before # if you want to navigate to a part of the same page.

Comment: @karthikaruna: I have also done that but it still breaks meaning it throughs the error that is shown above. Is their a file I need to call for this to work

Comment: `<p id="Espanol">` not `href="#Espanol"`. On click of footer link `href="#Espanol"`, the page will be scrolled to the element containing the `id` Espanol.

Comment: @karthikaruna I have also tried the id approach as well. Keeps crashing

Comment: @karthikaruna Thank you for your help. Found the issue.